# Save game files location for Shatter

Tags: shatter

I'm playing Shatter on Steam and I want to backup my saves, but I can't find the location of the save game files. Where are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shatter on Steam stores your savegame in the Steam Cloud; There is no need to backup your save.

Comment: Has it always been like that? Cause I did loose saves I had from a few months back.

Comment: I think it's more appropriate to say, there's no save you can backup.

Comment: @badp technically, there is the local cache; however, this is not used to store your save back in the cloud.